# Regex for string but at least one character must be a number or letter

Tags: validation, regular-expressions, lightninginput

I have a lightning input component and I need the input values to be only alphanumeric characters, underscores and/or spaces. However, there is also one more requirement to have at least one number or letter in the string (lest there be a string composed entirely of underscores and/or white-spaces). For the first condition, I have found that the regexp is `^[\w ]+$`. How do I modify this regexp such that I can also fulfill the second condition?

Comment: This question, being chiefly regex, might be a better fit on StackOverflow. My gut feeling, though, is that you can't fulfill both requirements in a single regexp. Multiple regex could probably do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd just have to specify that there's a requirement of at least one letter or number somewhere in the string. Here's a possible solution:

```
^(\w| )*[0-9A-Za-z](\w| )*$
```

This says we must match zero or more word characters (0-9, a-z, A-Z, and underscore) or a space, one letter or number, followed by zero or more word characters or a space.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want you regex to look like this:

```
\w*\d
```

Where `\w` matches all word characters and the `*` matches the previous the condition and `\d` looks numeric numbers

Comment: This should be close, but the requirement is to also capture spaces, so I think:
`\w* *\d` would cover that.